# Issue while submitting app to iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, xcode

I just completed making an app in Xcode 6.1 (GM), i have Mac OS X Yosemite GM and all the new updates.

When i submitted my application in the iTunesConnect website it says,"Apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 SDK"

Need help, how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 6.1 includes the iOS 8.1 beta SDK. You can't submit to the app store using a beta SDK. You'll have to download Xcode 6.0.1 from the Mac app store. Be sure to rename Xcode 6.1 so that the app store doesn't overwrite it.

Comment: Do i need to create the entire app again? Or i can just open that xcode project in 6.0.1 and set the iOS version to 8? Will it work?

Comment: @PunitKhatri Yes, just open the project in Xcode 6.0.1 and build with the iOS 8 SDK.